# Calling the equals the wrong way?

Tags: java, equals

I was using a PriorityQueue, and I overrode the equals in MyClass,

```
PriorityQueue<MyClass> pq = ...
```

I wanted to make some foreign objects equals to MyClass,

```
if (pq.contains(foreignObj)) {
   ...
}
```

When I looked into the implementation of PriorityQueue, it called this way,

```
o.equals(queue[i])
```

Where 'o' was the foreignObj and 'queue[i]' was an instance of MyClass.  That caused a major problem, because I expected it called MyClass's equals because I own that so I could make any types of objects 'equals' to mine.  And, I don't own the foreign class's source code and could not change anything over there.

Why it didn't code as below, so it'd call my equals instead of someone else's that I don't have control of?

```
queue[i].equals(o)
```

Comment: `instead of someone else's that I don't have control of?` Generally speaking, classes of different types (`MyClass` vs `YourClass`) cannot be compared.  They are always not equal.

Comment: How exactly can it make sense that a `MyClass` instance is equal to an instance of the foreign class? Is `MyClass` a subclass?

Comment: In addition to the John's answer: Take a look at "Effective Java". This is a very cool book, and in 3rd edition, Item 10, it describes this issue.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Callers can expect `a.equals(b)` and `b.equals(a)` to have the same result no matter what `a` and `b` are, as long as they're non-null. It is guaranteed by the contract of the `equals` method.

Your implementation is not legal because it isn't *symmetric*. Per the [API documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/19/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Object.html#equals(java.lang.Object)):

> The `equals` method implements an equivalence relation on non-null object references:
>
> - It is *reflexive*: for any non-null reference value `x`, `x.equals(x)` should return `true`.
> - It is *symmetric*: for any non-null reference values `x` and `y`, `x.equals(y)` should return `true` if and only if `y.equals(x)` returns `true`.
> - It is *transitive*: for any non-null reference values `x`, `y`, and `z`, if `x.equals(y)` returns `true` and `y.equals(z)` returns `true`, then `x.equals(z)` should return `true`.

Comment: And in practice it's almost impossible to meet this criteria with different types (different classes).  Unless you control both classes and are *very careful* with how they are implemented.

Comment: @markspace or if both classes implement an interface that defines how it's equals work (as the JDK collection interfaces do).

Answer (score 0):

The code is written to give you the maximum amount of control. When you call `contains`, you choose what object you pass as an argument, and the Java queue implementation calls (virtually) the `equals` method *on that* object. If you don't like how `foreignObj.equals` is implemented, then wrap `foreignObj` in a minimal class that contains it and that overrides `equals` to do whatever you want.

```
public class MyObject {
  private ForeignObject foreignObj;

  public MyObject(ForeignObject foreignObj) {
    this.foreignObj = foreignObj;
  }

  @Override
  public boolean equals(Object that) {
    // ... Whatever you want ...
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The idea for Java containers are that you expect all objects in the container to be of the same type (or if they have different types, that instances of different types will never be equal), so it doesn't really matter on which direction you call `equals()` (as it is supposed to be insensitive to the order of arguments).

What you are trying to do goes against this basic assumption. If you are doing weird things, you might as well make it weirder and use a wrapper class that just reverses the order of `equals()` and use that to wrap your foreign object:

```java
class UndirectEq {
private Object v;
public UndirectEq(Object val) { v = val; }
boolean equals(Object o) { return o.equals(v); }
}

...

if (pq.contains(new UndirectEq(foreignObj))) { ...
```